# Sending email text/html fails

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send and email text or/and html versions..

What I do is this:

```
 $bodyHTML = "
 --PHP-alt-$random_hash 
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset='iso-8859-1' 
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

http://example.com/app_dl.php?app_id=$_GET[app_id] to download your $app_name app \n\r
Want to get tons more hot apps for free! anywhere anytime? Download our app on http://example' \n\r\n\r
example.com team

  --PHP-alt-$random_hash 
 Content-Type: text/html; charset='iso-8859-1'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

 <p><a href='http://example.com/app_dl.php?app_id=$_GET[app_id]'>Click Here</a> to download your $app_name app</p>
 <p>Want to get tons more hot apps for free! anywhere anytime? Download our app on <a href='http://example.com'>example.com</a></p>
 <br/>
 <p>example.com team</p>
  --PHP-alt-$random_hash ";
endif;
```

This is what I get:

```
--PHP-alt-f4b83c7072ae970392b44308a6c36109 Content-Type: text/plain; charset='iso-8859-

    1' Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit http://example.com/app_dl.php?app_id=35 to download your PhoneMates app Want to get tons more hot apps for free! anywhere anytime? Download our app on http://example.com' example.com team --PHP-alt-f4b83c7072ae970392b44308a6c36109 Content-Type: text/html; charset='iso-8859-1' Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
        Click Here to download your PhoneMates app
        Want to get tons more hot apps for free! anywhere anytime? Download our app on example.com

   example.com team
    --PHP-alt-f4b83c7072ae970392b44308a6c36109
```

The problem is that I see all those header lines..content type..and the text lines fail to be formatted with '\n\r'..

Also, I dont know if I can achieve the effect that if one version fails.. html or txt,,then the other version will appear.. thanks for the help

Here is some of the code:

```
 $random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
 $boundary="PHP-alt-".$random_hash;
 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'Content-Type'=>  'multipart/alternative',
   'boundary'=>$boundary,  
   'To' => $to,
    'Return-Path' => 'info@example.com',
   'Subject' => $subject);
```

Other details such as sender, pass , title,,arent relevant..so I didnt present them here..

Comment: How are you sending this html string, with `mail()`?  There's a parameter for adding additional headers.  They should be separate from the HTML.

Comment: `http://example.com/app_dl.php?app_id=$_GET[app_id]` — So I'll just add `app_id=@example.com/malware` and use your site to send out spam shall I? Don't put unsanatised data in the emails you send out!

Comment: I use it with pear Mail function ... $mine = new Mail_mime;
 $mine -> setHTMLBody($bodyHTML);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't roll your own MIME handling. Use a library instead of reinventing the wheel.

I understand that [Swift](http://swiftmailer.org/) is the usual option in PHP land.

That said, I suspect the problem has something to do with the whitespace before your MIME boundary markers and headers. Try removing it.

Also your last MIME boundary is missing the `--` at the end.

*Really, really*, use a robust, well tested, third party library for this stuff. There is just too much fiddly stuff you can get wrong.

Comment: what mime is missing --.. they all have that --

Comment: while I agree with you about the robustness of a library, I'd say that the discouragement you're offering will probably stop him from really learning about the process of mixed MIME type handling, which is a shame

Comment: Unless `$random_hash"; includes `--` at the end, **none** of them have it (but only the last one should).

Comment: Do u mean the last line should be: --PHP-alt-$random_hash --";

Comment: No. `--PHP-alt-$random_hash--`

Answer (score 1):

when i wrote my own, as you're doing now, this was the final set of headers that ended up being the correct, working setup.

```
//headers - specify your from email address and name here
//and specify the boundary for the email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "To: ".$to."\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary=" . $boundary . "\r\n";
```

also, my boundary, in context, looks like this:

```
$message .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $boundary . "--";
```

presumably, you need those trailing dashes.

Comment: I dont know if it would matter..But  I will put the mime version